# Accessing Jupyter Server Running on EC2 Through Bastion with SSH Tunnel

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-tunnel

So I've got an ec2 instance that I can only access through a bastion.

The ec2 instance serves my jupyter server on `127.0.0.1:8888/?token=$token`

The goal in mind that I have is to run an ssh tunnel command that will listen for connections on `127.0.0.1:8888`, and forward them through the bastion to my ec2 instance to `127.0.0.1:8888`

I've tried the following with no luck.

**from local**:

(I can ssh into both the bastion and the ec2 machine through the bastion without issue)

`ssh -f -N -L 127.0.0.1:8888:127.0.0.1:8888 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $user@$bastion_dns`

`ssh -f -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8888 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $user@$bastion_dns`

`ssh -f -N -L 8888:$ec2_private_ip:8888 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $user@$bastion_dns`

**from bastion**:

(I opened 8888 ingress on bastion security group and added bastion ssh key to ec2-machine so that I can ssh to ec2 regularly from the bastion)

`ssh -f -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8888 $user@$ec2_private_ip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of this [SSH Tunnel through Ubuntu bastion to instance in private subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768726/ssh-tunnel-through-ubuntu-bastion-to-instance-in-private-subnet?rq=1)

The command is:

`ssh -v -N -A -J $user@$bastion_dns -L 8888:localhost:8888 $user@$ec2_private_ip`

Answer (score 2):

When using `-L`, you can specify where the receiving machine should send the traffic.

Let's say you have:

- Local computer
- Bastion
- Jupyter server

Therefore, you can run a command like this:

```
ssh -i key.pem -L 8888:jupyter-server:8888 ec2-user@bastion-IP
```

This will forward `localhost:8888` on the local computer to the Bastion server.

The bastion server will then forward the request to `jupyter-server:8888`, within the VPC.